# Self Host Web Api + IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I have IIS installed and running on my machine. 
I also have self hosted WebApi.

If I configure WebApi service to listen to locahost:80, it overrides IIS and correctly serves requests. IIS not longer serves.

If I configure WebApi service to listen to subdomain.mydomain.com:80, whereas IIS to serve all other *.mydomain.com:80 they correctly work side by side.

How is it possible that these two share 80 port?

Comment: Does this really seem like a mystery to you?  Seems perfectly *possible* to me.  In the first case, you've told WebApi to service all port 80 requests; in the second case, you've told WebApi to only service `subdomain.mydomain.com:80` and let the remaining service requests pass through to IIS.

Comment: It does. Have you ever tried to listen to the same port from two services? You will get "Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:XXX/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.". Thus, IIS or WebApi does something that allows sharing 80 port. My guess is that WebApi detects IIS is installed on machine and registers in it, so IIS proxies requests to the service.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable theory to me.  It's clearly *possible,* since you've already proven that it works.